# How to count the number of rows in p:dataTable Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to Primefaces.

I am developing a project using Primefaces 5.1 and jsf 2.2.

I do not know how to count the number of rows in `p:dataTable`?

I need this for set Piechart based on rows count.

Any idea?

Comment: do you want to acces the row count fron Javascript or from Java ManagedBean?

Comment: @Kishor P,I need to access the rows count by using Javascript......

Answer (score 4):

What yo have to do is to set a `widgetVar` to your `p:datatable`

```
<p:dataTable value="#{tableBean.myTable}" widgetVar="myTable">...</p:dataTable>
```

then you can use it to easily access your table from Javascript

To count the number of rows on your table

```
PF('myTable').tbody[0].children.length
```

or if you are using a paginator

```
PF('myTable').cfg.paginator.rowCount
```

Answer (score 0):

If `number of rows` means, how many datasets are returned from the backing bean to my view, then you should count the number of rows in your backing bean by simply adding another getter like

```
public int getNumberOfRows() {
  return this.myDataTableList.size();
}
```

If you mean by `number of rows`, how much data is currently visible within my `p:datatable` and you've used a `paginator`, then the answer is the same number you chose to initialize your datatable (except the last page maybe).

If you want to access the number of rows on the client side, you have to use something like this:

```
$("#YOUR_DATATABLE_ID").find(".ui-datatable-tablewrapper").find(".ui-datatable-data").find(".ui-widget-content").length
```

But this will only display the rows currently visible (if you are using a paginator). If you want to get all rows and to make it much easier for you, make the number of rows accessible in your backing bean as seen above.

Comment: ,Thakz for ur post....but ,I need to access the rows count by using Javascript......

Comment: Manuel@,Thanks for ur reply but Its not works for me...Its always gives the result is size 0 only.but in my table has three rows...

Comment: What not exactly? If you could create a jsfiddle it would be much easier to help you. (Again, doing it in JS is not the best way)

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of rows for a datatable, simply use the "size()" built in Java method

```
<p:dataTable value="#{tableBean.myTable}">...</p:dataTable>

<h:outputText value="#{tableBean.myTable.size()}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still needs this feature **just for display purposes**. 
From Version 5 upwards you have the so called {CurrentPageReport} element in the paginator template. It allows customization via. Search for "currentPageReportTemplate" in the Primefaces documentation, it is kinda hidden :) [Primefaces 5.1 Docu](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_1.pdf)

With {totalRecords} you can output the number of records in the table. It also works with active filters. Here is an example:

```
<p:dataTable var="entry" value="#{mbvHandler.entries}"
      widgetVar="carsTable" id="carsTable"
      scrollable="true" scrollWidth="100%"
      filteredValue="#{mbvHandler.filteredEntries}"
      rows="25" paginator="true" resizableColumns="true"
      paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {Exporters}"
      currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} of {totalPages} ({totalRecords})"
      rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,25,50">
```